# Separate dataset according last two column

Tags: python, dataset

I am trying to separate my dataset according to last two column.
In 3rd column data frequency are 1,2,3,4. I want to separate my data for 0 and 1 for each value in column 3. For example:

for 1 in 3rd column and 0 and 1 in 4th column
{0: [[1, 20, 1, 0],[5, 20, 1, 0]]
1: [[8, 21, 1, 1]]}

for 2 in 3rd column and 0 and 1 in 4th column
{0: [[2, 21, 2, 0],[3, 22, 2, 0],
1: []}

for 3 in 3rd column and 0 and 1 in 4th column
{0: [[6, 23, 3, 0]]
1: [[4, 23, 3, 1]]}

for 4 in 3rd column and 0 and 1 in 4th column
{0: [[8, 22, 4, 0]]
1: [[7, 24, 4, 1]]}

Here is my Jupyter code

```
def separate_by_class(dataset):

    separated = {}
    for j in range(4+1): 
        for i in range(len(dataset)):
            row = dataset[i]
            if row[-1]==j:
                if row[-1] not in separated:
                    separated[row[-1]] = []
                separated[row[-1]].append(row)
    return separated   

dataset = [[1, 20, 1, 0],
           [2, 21, 2, 0],
           [3, 22, 2, 0],
           [4, 23, 3, 1],
           [5, 20, 1, 0],
           [6, 23, 3, 0],
           [7, 24, 4, 1],
           [8, 22, 4, 0],
           [9, 21, 1, 1]
          ]
separated =separate_by_class(dataset)
separated
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the format of desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not mentioned what is the desired output format but from what I understand you want to separate them into dictnoaries. You can try the following

```py
def separate_by_class(dataset):
  separated = {}

  for ar in dataset:
    if ar[2] not in separated:
      separated[ar[2]] = {}
    if ar[3] not in separated[ar[2]]:
      separated[ar[2]][ar[3]] = []
    separated[ar[2]][ar[3]].append(ar)

  return separated

separate_by_class(dataset)
```

The output of the function with your dataset would be

```py
{
 1: {0: [[1, 20, 1, 0], [5, 20, 1, 0]], 1: [[9, 21, 1, 1]]},
 2: {0: [[2, 21, 2, 0], [3, 22, 2, 0]]},
 3: {0: [[6, 23, 3, 0]], 1: [[4, 23, 3, 1]]},
 4: {0: [[8, 22, 4, 0]], 1: [[7, 24, 4, 1]]}
}
```